# how to go to the next page using django paginator?

Tags: python, django

I have something like this:

```
myobj = paginator_method(request, myresult)
return render_to_response(' ', myobj, context)
```

And when I am going to page 2 and onward its giving `MultiValueDictKeyError`:

> Key 'name' not found in `<QueryDict: {u'page': [u'2']}`

Comment: What is `myobj` that is returned by `paginator_method`? `render_response` needs a dictionary or Context object.

Answer (score 0):

```
return render_to_response(' ', dict(pagination=myobj, data=myresult), context)
```

.

```
{{ pagination.somevar }}
{{ data.somevar }}
```